# Changing type of python keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there an easy way to change the keys from strings to tuples in pythons?
E.g.:

```
dict = {'100,2': 0.3, "2,5" = 0.5}
```

Comment: Do you want a 2-tuple of strings, or a 2-tuple of ints?  (This is why it's a good idea to give an exact example of what you're after.)

Comment: don't name your dictionaries `dict`.  It shadows the `dict` built-in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> d = {'100,2': 0.3, "2,5": 0.5}
>>> d = {tuple(k.split(',')): v for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d
{('100', '2'): 0.3, ('2', '5'): 0.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested dict to get that kind of effect:

```
dict = {'100': {'2': 0.3},
        '2': {'5': 0.5}}
dict['100']['2']
=> 0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

```
>>> key = (100,2)
>>> value = 0.3
>>> d = {}
>>> d [key] = value
>>> d [key]
0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 d = {'2,5': 'a', '2,6': 'b'}
 e= {}
 for x in d.keys(): e[tuple(x.split(','))]=d[x]
 print e
{('2', '6'): 'b', ('2', '5'): 'a'}
```

Answer (score 0):

longer way of doing it, but it shows you how you could go about getting the result you want.

```
dict = {'100,2': 0.3, "2,5" : 0.5}

k = dict.keys()

for i in range(len(k)):
     k[i] = tuple(k[i].split(','))

newDict = {}

for i, key in enumerate(dict.keys(), 0):
    newDict[k[i]] = dict[key]

dict = newDict
print dict
```

Output:

```
{('100', '2'): 0.3, ('2', '5'): 0.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an answer in case it's what you want.  You can directly define the dictionary with tuples as keys:

```
>>> tuple_dict = {(100, 2): 0.3, (2, 5): 0.5}
>>> tuple_dict[(100,2)]
0.3
```

If it's converting '(100,2)' to a tuple that's a problem, and only explicit constants are involved, then you can try:

```
>>> eval('(100,2)', None, None)
(100, 2)
```

The `None` arguments prevent values of the program variables from leaking out into userland.